# Значение слова "ходовик"

Tags: лексикология

Согласно словарям слово "ходовик" имеет следующее значение.

Проф. Маршрут, по которому почтальон обходит свой участок. Составить, уточнить х. Придерживаться ходовика.

Но у нас в Армении (редко в России, судя по объявлениям) это слово используется в другом значении: специалист по ремонту ходовых частей автомобиля, в широком смысле слова: автослесарь. Но это значение в словарях не представлено.

Хотелось бы узнать, известно ли это значение вам?

Comment: Вечер добрый, Серж! Хорошей зимней погоды и благих праздников! P. S. Еще: "объявлениям" — лишнее. И скобочка прилепилась. И — значение слова «ходовик».

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, спасибо! Правку делали вы? Если да, то я отклонил только из-за тире. В остальном — согласен.

Comment: Я делал. Из-за какого тире? Я вроде не убирал и не ставил никаких тире. Или вы имеете в виду двоеточие? Мне показалось не очень удачным, что их два в предложении.

Comment: Да, тире вместо двоеточия.

Comment: Нет, я просто убрал двоеточие, не ставил тире вместо него первый раз, а теперь уже не трогал его.